# Obrigatoriedade do método private no construtor em Angular

Tags: angular

Porque é obrigatório a utilização do modificador de acesso `private` no método construtor em Angular?
Eu sei que eles são utilizados para não deixar que outros métodos visualizem/utilizem/modifiquem eles fora do método construtor, mas eu não entendi porque isso é uma obrigatoriedade. Estava construindo uma classe que lista todas as moedas de um método no Service.

```
constructor(
    private moedaService: MoedaService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.moedas = this.moedaService.listarTodas();
    this.init();
```

Quando eu tirei o `private` do método construtor deu erro no meu método `listarTodas` e não compilou.
Alguém consegue me explicar porque isso aconteceu?

Comment: não é obrigatório, a questão é que está usando abaixo o próprio parâmetro (no método `ngOnInit`. Se declarar a variável antes do construtor, no contrutor não é preciso usar private, mas vai precisar associar o parâmetro à variável... lembrando que poderia ser qualquer modificador de acesso como `public`, apenas como para ilustratura que é um "obrigatório" ser private

Comment: veja esse exemplo onde a variável é declarada fora do construtor (há exemplo das duas maneiras): https://gist.github.com/jhades/a17be59e153a01e9f65869caa5a80e12#file-02-ts

Answer (score 1):

Conforme foi comentado, não é obrigatório. O que ocorre é que o TypeScript oferece este tipo de sintaxe para criar uma [propriedade na sua classe](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties).
Então ao invés de declarar a propriedade no escopo da classe e então alimentá-la com o valor que chega em um argumento do construtor, podemos simplesmente utilizar o `private`, `public`, `protected` ou `readonly` para isto. Veja abaixo:

```
class MinhaClasse {
    parametro: string;

    constructor(parametro: string) {
        this.parametro = parametro;
    }
}
```

É a mesma coisa que escrever:

```
class MinhaClasse {
    constructor(private parametro: string) {
    }
}
```

Tendo este `parametro` como uma propriedade da sua classe, seu valor pode ser acessado dentro da sua classe e fora caso utilize o `public` ao invés do `private`.

Deixo como sugestão utilizar [este link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) para estudar como seu código TypeScript ficará em JavaScript.

Comment: Sua resposta ficaria ainda melhor se adicionasse que ao invés de usar `private`, é possível usar `public`, `protected` ou `readonly` também.

Comment: Muito obrigado @wldomiciano